# Mean value of the fixed interval in the column

Tags: matlab

The idea is to calculate the mean of the fixed intervals in the column.

For example, `A` is a 30x1 vector

```
A = [1.99116598579953
1.99130458744713
1.99130275791797
1.99130076212379
1.99129732263637
1.99129554481068
1.99129253092248
1.99128919331283
1.99128626646018
1.99128246022340
1.99127910416334
1.99127449885866
1.99126838746186
1.99126266917557
1.99125588988770
1.99124956601103
1.99126589366625
1.99124606011343
1.99126958257006
1.99123953491790
1.99120496980550
1.99117314162230
1.99113868160464
1.99110378123068
1.99106504737775
1.99103199236620
1.99099943597514
1.99097000143012
0.0845141896302122
0.0755554572754849];
```

The fixed interval is 3, which means the output `B` is a 10x1 vector containing mean value of each interval.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Straightforward group elements in `A` into triplets and then `mean`.

```
% method 1
B1 = reshape(A,3,10);
B1 = mean(B1,1)';
```

Method 2: Build index matrix and then find `mean` of each group of index. In this way you can adjust the index number individually if needed.

```
% method 2
B2 = bsxfun(@plus, repmat(0:3:27,3,1), [1;2;3])';
B2 = mean(A(B2),2);
```

Method 3: Group the elements in `A` and then apply `splitapply` according to the grouping. You can change the grouping pattern freely.

```
% method 3
B3 = repmat(1:10,3,1);
B3 = splitapply(@mean, A,B3(:));
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. However, the reshape function may exist some problems when the vector number can not be divisible.  I do find the r0 = mean(buffer(A,3)) is a better way to solve my question.